# No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

I’m keep getting the above error when trying to execute  Start-AzureService.

Following information prompted when executing Get-AzureAccount:

```
Id                    Type Subscriptions                        Tenants                               
--                    ---- -------------                        -------                               
Me@outlook.com User   12345678-1234-5678-9012-345678901235 {12345678-1234-5678-9012-345678901235}
```

And following information prompted when executing Get-AzureSubscription:

```
SubscriptionId            : 12345678-1234-5678-9012-345678901235
SubscriptionName          : My Production (Pay-As-You-Go)
Environment               : MyCloud
DefaultAccount            : Me@outlook.com
IsDefault                 : True
IsCurrent                 : True
TenantId                  : 12345678-1234-5678-9012-345678901235
CurrentStorageAccountName :  


Select-AzureSubscription : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
```

is prompted when When I try to follow the suggested command:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Default "My Production (Pay-As-You-Go)"
```

Answer (score 15):

Use this one to select your default subscription:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName "My Production (Pay-As-You-Go)"
```

You can also choose to use `-SubscriptionId` (and the GUID) instead of the name.

For more information on the `Select-AzureSubscription` commandlet; type `Get-Help Select-AzureSubscription` .

If this doesn't work, try running first, before selecting your subscription:

```
 Add-AzureAccount
```

Update if you're still facing trouble:

If you are using AzureRM / with old cmdlets (or just AzureRM) and are still facing problems I would strongly recommend you to check if you have multiple versions of AzureRM.Profile module . I've encountered this numerous times when one version is installed under Program Files and another under my user profile (or somewhere else in PSModulePath).

To list what modules / versions are installed :

```
Get-Module AzureRm.Profile -ListAvailable
```

If you have multiple instances and versions of this it might create some trouble with some of your cmdlets.

Comment: To get help, it's actually `Get-Help`.

Comment: Hi CmdrTchort, 
Not helps. 
Using Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName "My Production (Pay-As-You-Go)" prompts we with "WARNING: Current and Default parameters have been deprecated. Select-AzureSubscription will always update the Default Subscription" and Start-AzureService : No default subscription has been designated. 
When afterword’s try to use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription. is prompted again when trying to use Start-AzureService -PassThru -Profile STAGING -ServiceName myService.

Answer (score 9):

When I tried to `Select-AzureSubscription` it was giving me the error "Subscription does not exist" when I was passing 100% correct subscription name or subscription Id that I found on Azure portal and from powershell:

```
$account = Login-AzureRmAccount
$account.Context.Subscription.SubscriptionId
$account.Context.Subscription.SubscriptionName
```

Adding Azure account fixed the problem for me:

```
Add-AzureAccount
```