# Get-AzureWebsiteJob : No default subscription has been designated

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

[I am using and edited version of the script in the first answer on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40400457/how-to-list-all-running-webjobs-within-an-azure-subscription-using-powershell).  I first login, select the appropriate subscription, then get the Azure Rm Context.  I get this error when I do this:

> Get-AzureWebsiteJob : No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default  to set the default subscription.

The script:

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId subidguid
Get-AzureRmContext

$groups = get-AzureRmResourceGroup

foreach($group in $groups){

    $webApps = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $group.ResourceGroupName

    foreach($webApp in $webApps){

        write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $webApp.Name        

        ### ERROR HAPPENS
        $job = Get-AzureWebsiteJob -Name $webApp.Name

        if($job){ 
            write-host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow $job.JobName
        }        

        $job = Get-AzureWebsiteJob -Name $webApp.Name -Slot staging

        if($job){
            write-host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow $job.JobName " -staging"
        }
    }
}
```

I do get the names of the web apps outputted on the screen, but when it looks for webjobs, I get that error.  I tried the below technique based on the error, but this didn't help (edited the full code to make it clear what changes I made even though I still got the same error):

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId subidguid
Get-AzureRmContext

$groups = get-AzureRmResourceGroup

foreach($group in $groups){

    $webApps = Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName $group.ResourceGroupName

    foreach($webApp in $webApps){

        write-host -ForegroundColor Yellow $webApp.Name        

        ### ERROR HAPPENS
        Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId subidguid                
        $job = Get-AzureWebsiteJob -Name $webApp.Name

        if($job){ 
            write-host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow $job.JobName
        }        

        ### ERROR HAPPENS                
        Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId subidguid                
        $job = Get-AzureWebsiteJob -Name $webApp.Name -Slot staging

        if($job){
            write-host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow $job.JobName " -staging"
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially, before getting the web job details, I am first selecting the subscription id (shortened):

```
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId subidguid
$job = Get-AzureWebsiteJob -Name $webApp.Name
```

Executing ...

Select-AzureRmSubscription -Default -SubscriptionId subguidid

Throws a different error:

> Set-AzureRmContext : Missing an argument for parameter
>   'DefaultProfile'. Specify a parameter of type 
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IAzureContextContainer'
>   and try again.

I've tried using the `DefaultProfile` parameter instead of `Default`.  Regardless of what I pass in using `Default`, I get the error:

> Set-AzureRmContext : Cannot bind parameter 'DefaultProfile'. Cannot
>   convert the "WhatYouEntered" value of type "System.String" to type 
>   "Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.IAzureContextContainer".

I still get the same error.  When I look at the parameters allowed in the function of `Get-AzureWebsiteJob`, I don't see an option to specify the subscription.  Given that the jobs should be searched for by web apps, and the web apps return, why does this not find it by subscription id here?

Answer (score 1):

`Get-AzureWebsiteJob` is Azure Service Management PowerShell Module.

You need to use `Add-AzureAccount` to use the following cmdlet.

Use this one to select your default subscription:

```
Select-AzureSubscription -Default -SubscriptionName "My Production (Pay-As-You-Go)"
```

You can also choose to use `-SubscriptionId` (and the GUID) instead of the name.

For more information on the `Select-AzureSubscription` commandlet; type `Get-Help Select-AzureSubscription` .

If this doesn't work, try running first, before selecting your subscription:

```
Add-AzureAccount
```

For more details, refer "[No default subscription has been designated. Use Select-AzureSubscription -Default <subscriptionName> to set the default subscription](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37908171/no-default-subscription-has-been-designated-use-select-azuresubscription-defau)".

Comment: Thanks; this was addressed in the second part of the answer.  If I run `Select-AzureRmSubscription ` with the GUID for subscription id before running `Get-AzureWebsiteJob`, I still get the same error.  As for the command, `Add-AzureAccoun`, that just asks me to log in again.

I can get the web app names, so it's able to return these, but getting the jobs for those web apps then generates the error about "WHAT SUBSCRIPTION AM I ON????" even if I specify that.

Answer (score 1):

For now, Azure classic web site move to Azure ARM module, we **can't** use `Get-AzureWebsiteJob` to get web jobs.

There is **no** direct equivalent in the ARM PowerShell Cmdlets.

We can use this command to list web app jobs:

```
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $AppService -ResourceType microsoft.web/sites/<Webjob-type> -ApiVersion $Apiversion
```

Here is an example:

```
$Apiversion = "2015-08-01"
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName jasonapp3 -ResourceType microsoft.web/sites/triggeredwebjobs -ApiVersion $Apiversion
```

[image]

Also we can use this command start or stop web jobs.

```
Invoke-AzureRmResourceAction -ApiVersion $Apiversion  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $ResourceName -ResourceType microsoft.web/sites/<Webjob-type> -Action start/stop  -Force
```

Delete a webjob:

```
Remove-AzureRmResource -ApiVersion $Apiversion  -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName -ResourceName $ResourceName -ResourceType microsoft.web/sites/<Webjob-type>/<Webjob-name> -Force
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.